# How to find the Fourier series for limacons?

Tags: geometry, ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-series, approximation

In paper [Shadows of rotating black holes approximated by
Durer-Pascal limacons](http://haegar.fh-swf.de/publikationen/pascal.pdf), the author tries to find an approximation to the equations

$$
x=\frac{r ∆+r Q^2 −M(r^2 −a^2)}{a(r −M)\sin θ}
$$ 
and 
$$
y^2=\frac{4r^2∆}{(r −M)^2}−(x+a\sinθ)^2
$$ 
where $∆ = r
^2 − 2Mr + a^
2 + Q^
2$

**Note:** $r$ does **not** represent the radius here, i.e $r\neq\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}$.

The author shows that the above equations can be approximated using limacon equation 
$$
(x
^2 +y^
2 −Ax)^
2 =B
^2
(x
^2 +y^
2
)
$$
for $Q=0$ and $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Then it was stated (without proof) that for different values of $\theta$ the
"paramters A and B are given by the following simple Fourier series"

$$
A_a(θ) = A_a \sin θ +0.2 \,a \sin^ 3
θ \cos ^2
θ
$$
$$
B_a(θ) = B_a +0.23M\left(
1−
\sqrt{
1-\frac{
a^4}{
M^4}}\right)
\cos^4
θ
$$

My question is how did the author use the fourier series to arrive at the above equations for the paramters A and B?

Comment: I'm not quite sure about that. As it follows from the last formulas for $A,B $, when $\theta\rightarrow0$ the coefficient $A$ tends to zero while $B$ stands finite nonzero. The limacon equation in this case turns into circle $x^2+y^2=B^2$. But at the same time $x$ tends to infinity when $\theta\rightarrow0$, as it follows from the first formula.

Answer (score 1):

The statement of the original paper, which is admittedly rather vague, is that for $Q=0$, the orbit of $x(\theta)$ and $y(\theta)$ as given in your question, can be approximated by the limacon $(x^2+y^2-A x)^2 = B^2(x^2+y^2)$. This approximation is *not* analytical, as far as I can see. Rather, to my mind, the author uses Table 11 in the original paper as data to determine $A$ and $B$. If the orbit was a real limacon, of course $A$ and $B$ would be constant. Here, the author fits a Fourier series for both $A$ and $B$ to the available data, numerically. 
Additional evidence of this procedure is the appearance of numerical (i.e. inexact) quantities '$0.2$' and '$0.23$' in the expansions for $A$ and $B$: if these were derived analytically, from the original equations, no such numerical approximations would have been necessary.